# Starting Spyder/Jupyter Kernel on Server headless

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, spyder

I want to connect my local spyder-ide to a remote spyder-kernel running on our ML-server. but as soon as i shut down the console, the kernel halts. is there a way to start the kernel in the background and keep it running ?

i can start a kernel with `python -m spyder_kernel.console` on the server and can connect to it. but this opens a ipython console on the server. as soon as I close it, the kernel shuts down. is there a possibilty to start this kernel like "nohup" or headless.

i can do it with `jupyter kernel&` , but then i'm missing the spyder functionalities like the variable explorer in the IDE.

thanks for your help !

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Is it not possible for you to do `python -m spyder_kernels.console&`

Comment: my bad. i'm so sorry. this works. i don't know what i tried this morning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python -m spyder_kernels.console&` resolved the question !